# Что делает этот запрос MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

есть такие запросы. Если первый,второй,третий я понял, то что делает четвертый? И можно ли его переписать без использования временной таблицы

```
$mysql->query('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tTags (title varchar(255))');

$mysql->query('INSERT INTO tTags VALUES '. rtrim($insertQueryValues, ','));

$mysql->query(
    'INSERT INTO tags (title)
         SELECT tTags.title
         FROM tTags
         LEFT JOIN tags ON 
             tTags.title = tags.title
         WHERE tags.title IS NULL'
);

$mysql->query(
    'INSERT INTO photo_tags (photo_id, tag_id)
         SELECT ' . $photoId . ', tags.id 
         FROM tTags
         INNER JOIN tags ON 
             tTags.title = tags.title
         LEFT JOIN photo_tags ON
             tags.id = photo_tags.tag_id AND
             photo_tags.photo_id = ' . $photoId . '
         WHERE photo_tags.tag_id IS NULL'
);
```

Comment: Pro tip: (1) выделить весь код, (2) нажать Ctrl+K, (3) посмотреть в предпросмотр снизу, (4) ..., (5) PROFIT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создает таблицу `tTags` и задает в ней параметры

Comment: К сожалению не совсем точно